# OpenCV Mat Problem: Difference between Histogram and this loop

Tags: c++, opencv

i am working on image processing project that i want to implement it on cuda with opencv (opencv 4.0 with cuda suport)and i am not good at c++.
for color correction between two images, i am using code from this link: (https://answers.opencv.org/question/178127/matching-colors-between-two-pictures-in-opencv/)

my goal is to implement this code on GPU. for that i tried to rewrite that code. i faced two problems:

1- Is there any Cuda implemented library for this purpose? (Same Functionality)

2- in rewriting function ((do1ChnHist)), it seams that this loop calculates 1D histogram (Is  that true?) :

```cpp
for (size_t p = 0; p<img.total(); p++)
    {
        if (mask(p) > 0)
        {
            uchar c = img(p);
            h(c) += 1.0;
        }
    }
```

but i can't replace it with :

```cpp
int histSize = 256;
float range[] = { 0, 256 }; //the upper boundary is exclusive
const float* histRange = { range };
bool uniform = false, accumulate = false;
calcHist(&img, 1, 0, Mat(), h, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
```

or rewrite it with this loop (For changing Mat >> GpuMat in future. unfortunately Opencv_cuda does not support GpuMat_<>, due to that i tried to rewrite loop with Mat):

```cpp
Mat h;
h = Mat::zeros(cv::Size(256, 1), CV_16U);
uchar x;
for (size_t m = 0; m < img.size().width; m++)
    {
        for (size_t n = 0; n < img.size().width; n++)
        {
            x = img.at<int>(Point(m, n));
            h.at<int>(Point(int(x),0)) += 1;
        }
    }
```

because ether of two options return different answer from main loop in do1ChnHist function...
thanks...

Answer (score -1):

Opencv has all the function u want

```
virtual void cv::cuda::TemplateMatching::match  (   InputArray  image,
InputArray  templ,
OutputArray     result,
Stream &    stream = Stream::Null() 
)   

void    cv::cuda::calcHist (InputArray src, OutputArray hist, Stream &stream=Stream::Null())
    Calculates histogram for one channel 8-bit image. More...

void    cv::cuda::calcHist (InputArray src, InputArray mask, OutputArray hist, Stream &stream=Stream::Null())
    Calculates histogram for one channel 8-bit image confined in given mask. More...
```

depends, could be 1D array, and could be 2D array, depends on color. You should learn some basic image processing principle first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  the link in my post consists code for color histogram matching of two images not template matching. i cant use calchist because calchist returns different answer from the main loop in do1ChnHist function. excuse me if my post isn't intelligible enough.  thanks